# How to find nearest smaller and larger number in Array in java?

Tags: java, arrays

How can I find the nearest smaller and larger number in an `Array`?

I have the list of numbers:

```
[3.4, 5.8, 1.2, 7.9, 9.6, 2.7, 6.2, 4.7, 0.6, 4.1]
```

and I want to find the just smaller and larger than 5.0 from the array. In this case, I want the nearest smaller number which is 4.7 and nearest larger 5.8 to 5.0.

is it possible without sorting? because I have to arrays. in one array I have x-axis values and in another array, i have yAxis value. If I sort the array, then I will not be able to get the corresponding y values for x.

Comment: sort the array then check the first value below `5.0` and the first value above `5.0` .

Comment: suppose you first try to sort the array and then find a method to your problem. You can sort the with `Arrays.sort(intArr);`

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem once you properly define "nearest": a value a<sub>i</sub> from the array is nearest to value v when abs(a<sub>i</sub>-v) for index i is minimal among all elements of the array.

Use `Math.abs(x)` to compute absolute value. Store the minimal one, along with the index of the element which produced it.

Do this separately for values above and below v.

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account that you really want a coordinate built from two array values, this uses Guava's Zip functionality to zip two streams.  Some sorting is involved, but because we're sorting Coordinates instead of the actual arrays, you're still able to get the final coordinate you're after.

```
import com.google.common.collect.Streams;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Stream;


public class ZipTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Double[] xCoordinates = {3.4, 5.8, 1.2, 7.9, 9.6, 2.7, 6.2, 4.7, 0.6, 4.1};
        Double[] yCoordinates = {4.3, 8.5, 2.1, 9.7, 6.9, 7.2, 2.6, 7.4, 6.0, 1.4};
        List<Double> xValues = Arrays.asList(xCoordinates);
        List<Double> yValues = Arrays.asList(yCoordinates);

       // Get coordinate whose x value is less than and closest to 5.0
       Optional<Coordinate> coord1 = getCoords(xValues, yValues)
               .filter(coord -> coord.x < 5.0)
               .sorted((c1, c2) -> Double.compare(c2.x, c1.x))
               .findFirst();
        System.out.println(coord1);

       // Get coordinate whose x value is greater than and closest to 5.0
       Optional<Coordinate> coord2 = getCoords(xValues, yValues)
               .filter(coord -> coord.x > 5.0)
               .sorted((c1, c2) -> Double.compare(c1.x, c2.x))
               .findFirst();
        System.out.println(coord2);
    }

    private static Stream<Coordinate> getCoords(List<Double> xValues, List<Double> yValues) {
        return Streams.zip(xValues.stream(), yValues.stream(), (x,y) -> new Coordinate(x,y));
    }

    private static class Coordinate {
        private final Double x;
        private final Double y;

        Coordinate(Double x, Double y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "(" + x + "," + y + ")";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorting is probably the easiest way, if you want to maintain their original index you could simply merge the two lists into pairs, or alternatively create a list of tuples something like (key, index). This way you could sort by the key and still maintain knowledge of the original index, with future look-ups being significantly faster (assuming you're making this check more than once)